# Prefetching unrelated model on arbitrary field equivalence

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a code like this:

```
for m in MyModel.objects.filter(...):
    mo = MyOtherModel.objects.get(myOtherField=m.myField)
    print("{:s}{:s}".format(m, mo))
```

This is inefficient because finding `mo` requires a new query to the database.

To avoid this I was thinking to use either `prefetch_related(Prefetch())` or `.annotate()`.

The problem with the first is that `Prefetch()` would need a foreignkey relationship between the 2 models (they have none).

Same thing .annotate:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(...).annotate(moWithSameField=F('myField') == F(???))
```

^ This would be also be wrong even if I knew what to write in `???`.

Is this possible to do? Can you prefetch something completely unrelated based on an arbitrary query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a different note, why don't you just read the whole querysets (for `MyModel` and `MyOtherModel`) into memory and then compare? Would be efficient in terms of number of queries to db

```
m_rows = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
m = m_rows.order_by('myField').values_list('myField')
m_set = set([x for x in m])
mo_rows = MyOtherModel.objects.all()
mo = mo_rows.values_list('myOtherField')
mo_set = set([x for x in mo])
common = list(m_set.intersection(mo_set))
mo_result = MyOtherModel.objects.filter(myOtherField__in=common).order_by('myOtherField')
for i in range(len(mo_result)):
    print("{:s}{:s}".format(m_rows[i], mo_rows[i]))
```

I believe this is overly complicated and there should be a better way to do this.
But this saves you n queries to db.

Comment: Yeah, it'd make much more sense to preload the unrelated queryset with __in and then compare with raw-Python list. I'll probably stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points:
1- If these queries will run in an operational system with large data by a user request, you need to redesign your ER model or consider other solutions.
2-If you don't have a lack of memory problem, you can load your whole objects of the models in memory with two queries.

```
MyOtherModelAll=MyOtherModel.objects.all()
for m in MyModel.objects.filter(...):
   for mo in MyOtherModelAll:
   if(mo.myOtherField=m.myField)
        print("{:s}{:s}".format(m, mo))
```

3. Annotate method tells Django to add an extra attribute to every object returned.The following sample me be usefull for you:

```
Book.objects.annotate(search=searchVector  ('title','abstract'),).filter(search='django')
```